# Strange behavior with dependency injection with @Autowired beans in test

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, automated-tests

I am experiencing an error from a `@SpringBootTest` that occurs very intermittently (maybe 2% of the time) which I cannot debug.  I am injecting 2 Spring Beans via `@Autowire` into this test.  One is a singleton scoped bean which is stateful, and another is a request scoped bean.  The request scoped bean ends up using the singleton scoped bean indirectly via a couple other singleton beans (all through dependency injection).

What's happening is I'm trying to put some mock data into the stateful singleton bean from my test, and then immediately access that data by calling a method on the request scoped bean.  Somehow the mock data I had just placed into the stateful bean is not there when the method on the request scoped bean is called, causing the error to be thrown.

The only thing I can think of is somehow the instance of the stateful singleton bean is different in the test versus the request scoped bean, but based on my understanding that shouldn't be possible?

I have the following bean configuration:

```
@Bean
SingletonBeanA singletonBeanA() {
  return new SingletonBeanA();
}

@Bean
SingletonBeanB singletonBeanB(SingletonBeanA singletonBeanA) {
  return new SingletonBeanB(singletonBeanA);
}

@Bean
SingletonBeanC singletonBeanC(SingletonBeanB singletonBeanB) {
  return new SingletonBeanC(singletonBeanB);
}

@Bean
@RequestScope
RequestScopeBean requestScopeBean(SingletonBeanC singletonBeanC) {
  return new RequestScopeBean(singletonBeanC);
}
```

with some additional singleton beans as dependencies for `SingletonBeanB` and `SingletonBeanC` omitted as they are not relevant.

`SingletonBeanA` is a stateful class which the `RequestScopeBean` indirectly reads from.

I have written a `@SpringBootTest` which has `SingletonBeanA` and `RequestScopeBean` injected via the `@Autowire` annotation.  In that test, I do the following:

```
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@SpringBootTest
@Import(SpringBootTestConfiguration.class)
class MyTest {

  @Autowire SingletonBeanA singletonBeanA;
  @Autowire RequestScopeBean requestScopeBean;

  private TestResult myTestHelperMethod(List<Stuff> stuff) {
    UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    singletonBeanA.putValueIntoMap(uuid, stuff);
    // this will end up reading the 'stuff' from the previous line
    return requestScopeBean.doSomething(uuid); 
  }

  @Test
  void myTestExample() {
    List<Stuff> mockData = List.of(...);
    TestResult testResult = myTestHelperMethod(mockData);
    // assertions on testResult
  }
}
```

There are 10 different test classes that each following the above pattern.  They are run in parallel (the classes are parallelized, not the tests within the classes).

All 10 of these tests pass ~98% of the time the test suite is run.  But very infrequently, I see this error when running these tests:

> Cannot invoke "java.util.List.iterator()" because the return value of "SingletonBeanA.getValueFromMap(java.util.UUID)" is null

Where the uuid passed to `getValueFromMap` was the same exact one generated by the test helper and passed into `RequestScopeBean.doSomething()`.

Why does the internal map within `SingletonBeanA` not contain the value that was just put there?  There is no code that ever removes stuff from the internal map of `SingletonBeanA`, so the only explanation I can come up with is that the instance of `SingletonBeanA` that was injected into my `RequestScopeBean` (via `SingletonBeanB` --> `SingletonBeanC`) is somehow different than the one that has been injected into my `@SpringBootTest` via `@Autowire`.

Because the issue happens so infrequently, it has been difficult to debug.  I am hoping someone knows what I'm doing wrong so that I can stop guessing and aimlessly searching the internet for answers.

Other details:

- All `@SpringBootTest`s in this project share the same test configuration in order to facilitate sharing the same `ApplicationContext`
- The tests are parallelized (class level) with there being 10 tests following the same example I outlined above
- There is no code that removes from the internal map in `SingletonBeanA` - it is a private structure with no exposed (nor private) method to remove data from it